# Absolutely positioned responsive circle

Tags: css, responsive-design, less

I am trying to build a responsive, rotating circle similar to the one in this screenshot http://grab.by/PRrw from the www.wove.com menu.

So far, I have a responsive circle using a percentage padding-top and width to make the circle fit a minimum 100vh div, and elements placed on that circle. The issue is ensuring that the elements on the circle remain in place when the browser is resized. Any ideas on the best approach to accomplish this?

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/szjkrbut/1/

The CSS

```
.radial-menu {
    border: solid 1px #999;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 105%;
    position: absolute;
    right: -50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 105%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.radial-item {
    display: block;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    width: 35%;
    max-width: 290px;

    &:after {
        background: #999;
        border-radius: 50%;
        content: '';
        height: 8px;
        position: absolute;
        right: -40px;
        top: 50px;
        transition: 300ms all ease;
        width: 8px;
    }
    &.item-1 {
        transform: rotate(22deg) translate(-231%, 35px);
    }
    &.item-2 {
        transform: rotate(0deg) translate(-237%, 35px);
    }
    &.item-3 {
        transform: rotate(-22deg) translate(-240%, 35px);
    }
}
```

Comment: At first glance you'd better to use `relative` positioning for `.radial-item`s and ensure they're relative (incl. all transforms) to the center of your `.radial-menu`.

Comment: Thanks @seven-phases-max It seems even with relatively positioned `.radial-items` and all percentage values for the transforms, the placement on the circle is not consistent when I resize my window.